# Processing form with no server-side script (javascript) + adding CSS inside of Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, document.write

I have been working on a very large form project for the past few days. I finally managed to get tables to work properly within a javascript file that opens a new display window. Now the issue at hand is that I can't seem to get CSS code to work within the javascript that I have created.

Before everyone starts thinking "just use server side script idiot" I have a few conditions and info about the file:

The file is only being ran local due to confidential information risks. Once again no option for server access. The intranet the computers are on are already top security and this wouldn't exactly be a company wide program

The code below is obviously just a demo with a simple form...

The real file has six pages of highly confidential information

Only certain fields on this form will actually be gathered (example: address doesnt appear in the results)

The display page will contain data compiled into tables for easier viewing

I need to be able to create css commands to easily detect certain information if it applies and along with matching design of the original form

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Example</title>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function display() {
DispWin = window.open('','NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=800,height=600')

message = "<body>";
message += "<table border=1 width=100%>";
message += "<tr>";
message += "<th colspan=2 align=center><font face=stencil color=black><h1>Results</h1><h4>one</h4></font>";
message += "</th>";
message += "</tr>";

message += "<td width=50% align=left>";
message += "<ul><li><b><font face=calibri color=red>NAME:</font></b> " +         document.form1.yourname.value + "</UL>"  
message += "</td>"; 

message += "<td width=50% align=left>";  

message += "<li><b>PHONE: </b>" + document.form1.phone.value + "</ul>";
message += "</td>";
message += "</table>";
message += "<body>";

DispWin.document.write(message);
DispWin.document.body.style.cssText = 'color:#blue;'; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form Example</h1>
Enter the following information:
<form name="form1">
<p><b>Name:</b> <input TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="20" NAME="yourname">
</p>
<p><b>Address:</b> <input TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="30" NAME="address">
</p>
<p><b>Phone: </b> <input TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="15" NAME="phone">
</p>
<p><input TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Display" onClick="display();"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
>
```

Comment: What's your question? What part of the CSS isn't working, and what result are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing the entire thing as JS, just make a call to a static page, and have a script change values as needed.

For instance, make your template:

whatever_after_post.html

```
<SomeKindOfDocType>
<html>
  <blahblah>
    <style> * { color: black} </style>
  </blahblah>
  <blahblah>
    <input type=text id="DatTing" />
  </blahblah>
</html>
```

Next, from the page that calls the creation of the new window, the same way you have ...

```
DispWin = window.open(...
```

Just open the template file, and use your reference to DispWin to access the methods to change values of that template the same way you change values on any other page (`window.getElementById` vs `DispWin.getElementById`). There's no reason to build the entire HTML file as a string inside of the JS that calls it... that's going to be harder to maintain, and you're going to have issues like the ones you're running into now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  tag to link to a CSS

Comment: not sure how that would work to get the dispwin. to pull the tag could you provide an example?

Comment: DispWin.document.write('<link href="something.css" />);